# Hard_fault on STM32 on second write to byte array - why?

Tags: c, stm32, framebuffer

I'm missing something obvious here. I get hardfault error on STM32  (CubeIDE) when trying to put working code in function...
This one works :

```
uint8_t framebuffer[SUBFBUF_XYMAX*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP];  //24 bpp framebuffer
...
          ii = rand() % SUBFBUF_XYMAX;
          jj = rand() % SUBFBUF_XYMAX;

          DrawPoint (ii,jj,framebuffer[0], 255, 255,255);
          framebuffer[ii*BPP+jj*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP] =  255;
          framebuffer[ii*BPP+jj*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP+1] =  255;
          framebuffer[ii*BPP+jj*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP+2] = 255;
```

but when I try to put this into function (in another file, shown below) I get HardFault on second write to framebuffer. 
There must be logical explanation on what is wrong...
This one doesn't work:

```
  DrawPoint (ii,jj,framebuffer[0], 255, 255,255);
```

and then function's definition

```
void DrawPoint(int x0, int y0, uint8_t framebuf[], uint8_t red, uint8_t green,uint8_t blue) {
    int temp=x0*BPP+y0*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP;

    framebuf[x0*BPP+y0*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP] = (uint8_t)blue;
    framebuf[x0*BPP+y0*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP+1] = (uint8_t)green;
    framebuf[x0*BPP+y0*SUBFBUF_XYMAX*BPP+2] = (uint8_t)red;

}
```

Thanks in advance,
regards,
R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `DrawPoint()`, use `framebuffer` or `&framebuffer[0]` instead of `framebuffer[0]`. The function expects a pointer, not a value.

Also, inside the definition of `DrawPoint()` you did not use `temp`, which would speed up your code.